# Transcript collisions and hash collisions in (password) key exchange protocol

Tags: hash, key-exchange, pake

In [New Security Results on Encrypted Key Exchange](https://escholarship.org/content/qt6p17j026/qt6p17j026.pdf), there is a Game 2 as follows:

Game $G_{2}$: For an easier analysis in the following, we cancel games in which some (unlikely) collisions appear:

- collisions on the partial transcripts $((A, X^{*}), (S, Y))$. Note that transcripts involve at least one honest party, and thus one of $X^{*}$ or $Y$ is truly uniformly distributed;
- collisions on the output of $\mathcal{G}$.

Both probabilities are bounded by the birthday paradox:

$Pr[Coll_{2}]\leq \frac{(q_{p}+q_{s})^{2}}{2q} +\frac{(q_{g})^{2}}{2q}$.

My questions are:

1. Why the authors design such a game to rule out the collisions of transcript and random oracle in this game? I do not know what is the meaning of this game?
2. Why the authors just rule out the collisions of random oracle $\mathcal{G}$ but not $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly you don't understand, and thus what exactly to clarify. Do you understand why this inequality holds? Or do you want us to explain this ?

Comment: I do not know why the authors design such a game to rule out the collisions of transcript and random oracle in this game? I do not know what is the meaning of this game?@Mikhail Koipish